# "Меж-"  - это приставка?

Tags: словобразование

Каким способом образовано слово **межрайонный**?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Межрайонный - это имя прилагательное, которое образовано префиксально-суффиксальным способом: приставка меж- и суффикс -н-. (меж-район-н-ый)

Comment: А почему не приставочным от слова районный?

Comment: "районный" образовано от слова "район"+ суф. -н- + окончание -ый.

Comment: да, районный образовано суффиксальным способом, а межрайонный - префиксальным  
район - районный - межрайонный

Comment: Почему минус -то? Плюс!

Comment: Хоть бы прокомментировали, почему минус за правильный ответ!

Comment: Дык потому, что правильный. 
Знаю, кто, но не скажу.  
Плюс - в качестве компенсации.

Answer (score 2):

Элен, в данном случае я с Вами не согласна. Словообразование начинается с определения: Межрайонный семинар - это семинар, проходящий между районами, значит, производящая основа - район+ приставка меж+суфф.-н-. Нельзя сказать "Это районный семинар, который находится между". Посмотрела у Тихонова в словообразовательном словаре. Он даёт гнездо, где от слова район образованы районный, внутрирайонный, межрайонный, порайонный. Значит, всё-таки суффиксально-префиксальный (суффиксально-приставочный).

Есть спорные случаи, но они касаются приставки бес-/без-.Безболезненный - без+ болезненный -без того, чтобы быть болезненным, - приставочный; без болезни - приставочно-суффиксальный, и то предпочтительно говорить о приставочно-суффиксальном, так как точнее прослеживается анализ семантики слова через основу -болезн-. В заданиях ЕГЭ даётся ответ суффикс.- прист.

Comment: Спасибо, поняла.